# Error for profile less info

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I press `less info` in my EE profile, some information are overlapped. See below:

[image]

I thought this could be only in my browser, but my `less info` profile from Stack Overflow is showing correctly:

[image]

---

## Edit:

I use Chrome, but I can reproduce this with IExplorer V10 too.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome

Comment: With the new user page (that no longer has a "less info" mode), I guess this is [meta-tag:status-completed] now.

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm this in Chrome too. For SE devs, this CSS rule appears to be the root of the problem:

```
.user-show-new .user-header .data {
    width: 318px!important;
}
```

Disabling that rule makes it work fine:

[image]

Comment: The real problem is that the selector is too broad, and matches elements it shouldn't. It's clearly *meant* to apply only in the expanded view, which means that it should read e.g. `.user-show-new .user-header-left .data` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the CSS rule pointed out by Chris Laplante is clearly meant to apply only in the expanded view.  To fix this problem, it should be changed to read something like this:

```
.user-show-new .user-header-left .data {  /* note the "-left"! */
    width: 318px !important;
}
```

Until this is properly fixed, I've added a patch for this bug to [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.28; this patch consists simply of the following extra CSS rule:

```
.user-show-new .user-header.user-header-slim .data {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

(The extra `.user-header` in the selector is there just to make this rule more specific than the broken rule quoted by Chris, and therefore able to override it.)